# JCE Cannot Authenticate the provider

Tags: bouncycastle, jce

I'm using Bouncy Castle as the provider. But when i load the keystore, I am getting JCE cannot authenticate provider BC exception. I understand that the jar has to be signed. I am using the signed jar from their site.

Here is the code

```
KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12", new BouncyCastleProvider());
char[] pin = args[1].toCharArray();
keystore.load(new FileInputStream(ksFile), pin);
```

Here is the stack trace

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: error constructing MAC: java.lang.SecurityException: JCE cannot authenticate the provider BC
at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.keystore.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStoreSpi.engineLoad(Unknown Source)
at java.security.KeyStore.load(Unknown Source)
```

Is it better if I go with the sun's implementation instead? It says here that the pkcs11 provider can't be run on windows 64 bit. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/p11guide.html#KeyStoreRestrictions Is there such a restriction for pkcs12 too?

Comment: Why are you specifying a provider at all?

Comment: Pkcs12's sun implementation can't be used in a 64bit machine. I want to know whether such a restriction is there for default provider that comes with Oracle jdk. Besides. I still don't know whether we'd be using pkcs11(token) or 12. Thought having bouncy castle in place wouldn't require me to revisit this code depending on keystore.